# sort datatable based on xml column node value

Tags: c#, xml, list, sorting, datatable

I get DataTable like this

```
ID  Name   Type   XML
1   Test   Pro    <sample><Name>xyz</Name><Type>xyz</Type><Date>2015-01-01</Date></sample>
2   Test2  Pro2   <sample><Name>abc</Name><Type>pqr</Type><Date>2015-01-02</Date></sample>
```

I convert this to class as shown below

```
Public class test
{
       public int ID{get;set;)
       public int Name{get;set;)
       public int Type{get;set;)
       public dictionary<string,string> XML{get;set;)
}
```

This XML contains node and its values as key value pair. Now, i want to sort this based on the user input. e.g. if user wants to sort by Date or name of Type. How to do that? Sort in either datatable or directly into the list will work.

I tried to sort in datatable but all the time result remains the same. Please provide any suggestions for the same.

Comment: So what is in that Dictionary? The keys Name, Type, Date with their value, right?

Comment: @rene : Yes. You got it right. All the xml nodes as a key and all the values inside that nodes as values e.g. Date = 2015-01-02 etc....

Answer (score 0):

You can use an instance of a class that implements [`IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) for your type. The comparer implementation then knows which rules to apply, for example when your type has a Dictionary.

Here is an example implementation to get you started. Do note that I didn't bother to implement all the different edge cases with null values. That is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public int Name{get;set;}
    public int Type{get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string> XML{get;set;}

    // this class handles comparing a type that has a dictionary of strings
    private class Comparer: IComparer<Test>
    {
        string _key;
        // key is the keyvalue from the dictionary we want to compare against
        public Comparer(string key) 
        {
            _key=key;
        }

        public int Compare(Test left, Test right) 
        {
            // let's ignore the null cases,
            if (left == null && right == null)  return 0;
            string leftValue;
            string rightValue;
            // if both Dictionaries have the key we want to sort on ...
            if (left.XML.TryGetValue(_key, out leftValue) && 
                right.XML.TryGetValue(_key, out rightValue)) 
            {
                // ... lets compare on those values
                return leftValue.CompareTo(rightValue);     
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // this method gives you an Instace that implements an IComparer
    // that knows how to handle your type with its dictionary
    public static  IComparer<Test> SortOn(string key)
    {
        return new Comparer(key);
    }
}
```

Use the above class in any [`Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes an IComparer, for example, on a plain List you can do:

```
list.Sort(Test.SortOn("Date"));
```

And that will sort the list.

To test the above code you can use this test rig:

```
var list = new List<Test> { 
    new Test {ID=1, Name =2, Type=3, 
        XML = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"Date","2017-09-01"}}},
    new Test {ID=10, Name =20, Type=30, 
        XML = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"Date","2017-01-01"}}},
    new Test {ID=100, Name =200, Type=300, 
        XML = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"Date","2017-03-01"}}},
        };

list.Sort(Test.SortOn("Date"));

list.Dump();
```